# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed). in Fifox

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have problem win API MVC 4 in visual studio 2010
in client side, I used Ajax:

```
    $.ajax
    ({
        headers:
                {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
                    'Access-Control-Request-Method':'*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'*',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'allow-navigation':'*'
                },
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://192.168.1.16:8080/api/Parameter/getGender",
        //contentType: "application/json",
        datatype: "json",
        async: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function successfunc(data)
        {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function failfunc(data) {
            alert('Error!');
        }
```

when I run in IE browser is OK, but I run it in firefox browser I see error:

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://192.168.1.16:8080/api/Parameter/getGender. (Reason: CORS preflight channel did not succeed)."